# How to set QueryClientProvider from tanstack/react-query in storybook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, react-query

In storybook, I'm getting the following error: `No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one`

[image]

In my _app.tsx:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};
```

I've tried to wrap the story in QueryClientProvider:

```
// method 1
export default {
  ...
  decorators: [
    (Story) => {
      const queryClient = new QueryClient();
      return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <Story />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      );
    },
  ],
} as Meta;

// method 2
export const Complete = () => {
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <AuthenticationPage />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};
```

But neither is working; I dug through the internet and all non of the solutions are for storybook specific.

Comment: both ways should work, so it's very hard to say without a runnable reproduction

Comment: I thought my implementation was correct as well; but just not working for some reason. I was thinking there might be a special case for the react-query library.

Comment: there is not. I can take a look if you can link to a public repo that has this issue

Comment: Much appreciated: https://github.com/weipeng-jiang/calories-to-meals
The story is src/components/authenticationPage/AuthenicationPage.stories.tsx

Comment: Please also note, the storybook code in my question is not in master yet

Comment: then how should I look at it? A more minimal repo would also be preferred to narrow it down

Comment: Apologies, I've added the storybook provider in AuthenicationPage.stories.tsx, please run npm i and npm run storybook

Comment: I have same issue react query cannot be seeing by storybook,how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix the issue by adding a decorator for query client into my story.

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default {
  title: "Home Page/MovieCard",
  component: MovieCard,
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{Story()}</QueryClientProvider>
    )
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrestled with what I thought was the same issue, and it turned out that I was making the query at the same level as I was specifying the provider. This goes against the React rendering lifecycle, as the query will be attempted before context is made available. I would double check that you aren't facing this, rather than a storybook-specific issue.

Comment: do you have some sample code/sandbox? or some other guidance on your structure?

Comment: I have same issue react query cannot be seeing by storybook,how to solve it?